# get the id from hasManyThrough relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables

Users table

[image]

Loan Amounts Table

[image]

Grant Loan amounts table

[image]

on my user model i used hasManyThrough relationship

```
public function loan_amounts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\LoanAmount',
        'App\GrantLoanAmount',
        'user_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'amount_id'
    );
}
```

this relationship display the loan_amounts->amount in my user.show blade.

so if i just do {{$user}} it display the following:

```
{
    "id":13,
    "name":"antonitte",
    "email":"antonitte!23@yahoo.com",
    "email_verified_at":null,
    "phone_number":"09472315875",
    "verification_code":null,
    "phone_verified_at":null,
    "avatar":"user.jpg",
    "created_at":"2019-09-23 18:50:57",
    "updated_at":"2019-09-23 18:50:57",
    "loan_amounts":[
        {"id":1,"amount":"5000.00","default":1,"created_at":"2019-09-23 02:45:30","updated_at":"2019-09-23 02:45:30","laravel_through_key":13},
        {"id":4,"amount":"20000.00","default":0,"created_at":"2019-09-23 02:46:37","updated_at":"2019-09-23 02:46:37","laravel_through_key":13},
        {"id":2,"amount":"10000.00","default":0,"created_at":"2019-09-23 02:46:08","updated_at":"2019-09-23 02:46:08","laravel_through_key":13}
    ]
}
```

which is good. But my problem is I want to grab the id of grant_loan_amounts->id. so that I can send it to GrantLoanAmountsController@destroy for deletion

[image]

any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can try using the eloquent relationships which can be found in the laravel document [querying-relationships (check on which laravel version you are using)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

From your example you can try something like the following:

this should return a collection

```
$user->loan_amounts->pluck('id');
```

this should help to turn into an array

```
$user->loan_amounts->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: Hi Jame. This gives the ID from loan amount table. what I wish to pull out is the ID from Grant Loan amount table